# MBProgressHud clears the view when showing the loader

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, mbprogresshud

I'm using MBProgressHud to show a load indicator. Here is my display code:

```
self.hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:self.hud];

self.hud.delegate = self;
self.hud.labelText = @"Loading :)";

[self.hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(CreateCollage) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

The issue is that when this runs, it clears out the view containing a bunch of photos. This is confusing for my user because they lose visual frame of reference.

If I don't use MBProgressHud, you would see the existing photo set until `CreateCollage` was finished, and it would kind of just lag or freeze into the next set, which is somewhat OK but not preferred. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is sourced by initializing it with the view and then adding it to the view again, so it is somehow identical to your view in terms of frame , so it may be getting in front.

I suggest trying this instead :

```
self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
self.hud.delegate = self;
self.hud.labelText = @"Loading :)";
```

And call this at the end of your action which is `CreateCollage`

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This doesn't seem to work, as when CreateCollage runs, it seems to take up enough resources that the loader doesn't show until the next set is complete. So basically, you'll only see the loader flash up right before the next set is shown in the view. However it does allow the existing photo set to remain in view.

Comment: I thought it was an async action. Of course if it is blocking this will not work